# Retrofit Android Response-Returns HTML Not JSON On POST 400

Tags: android, retrofit, rest

I am a newbie in Android. I have a rest API I developed in Django which I want my Android app to interact with.
I am using Retrofit In Android Studio
To save a new user through the API I pass four fields (staff_id,email,password,password2) to my API.

It all works fine in Postman and returns the appropriate responses for both a success (HTTP 200) and bad request (HTTP 400)

[This Is The Image of a 201 Response on The Android App Which is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4QTY.png)

However the HTTP 400 response in Android does not return a JSON. In Postman I get this for the HTTP 400
    {
        "error_message": "That email is already in use.",
        "response": "Error"
    }

But In Android I don’t get the Same JSON Response from the response.errorBody(). Instead I Get A HTML Response LIke This:

```
<DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 transitional//EN>
<html>
<head>
<title>400</title>
<meta http-eqiv="Cache-Control"
content ="no-cache"/>
</head>
<body>
<p>
Bad Request 
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here’s My Android Studio Code
Api.java:`

```
package nkemokongwu.com.ng.leave.activities.api;

import nkemokongwu.com.ng.leave.activities.models.NewStaff;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.Header;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface Api {
    @FormUrlEncoded

    @POST("authenticate/api/api_signup/")
    Call<ResponseBody> signup(
            @Field("staff_id") int staff_id,
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("password") String password,
            @Field("password2") String password2
    );


    @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("authenticate/api/api_login")
Call<ResponseBody> userLogin(
        @Field("email") String email,
        @Field("password") String password

);
```

}

**RetrofitClient.Java**

```
package nkemokongwu.com.ng.leave.activities.api;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://nsitf.pythonanywhere.com/";
    private static RetrofitClient mInstance;
    private Retrofit retrofit;
private RetrofitClient() {
    retrofit  = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}

public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new RetrofitClient();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public Api getApi() {
    return retrofit.create(Api.class);
}
```

}

**SignUpActivity.java**

```
package nkemokongwu.com.ng.leave.activities.authentication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

import nkemokongwu.com.ng.leave.R;

import nkemokongwu.com.ng.leave.activities.api.RetrofitClient;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;


public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private EditText editTextstaff_id,editTextemail,editTextpassword,editTextpassword2;

private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
    editTextstaff_id = findViewById(R.id.editTextstaff_id);
    editTextemail = findViewById(R.id.editTextemail);
    editTextpassword = findViewById(R.id.editTextpassword);
    editTextpassword2 = findViewById(R.id.editTextpassword2);

    findViewById(R.id.text_already_have_account).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUp).setOnClickListener(this);
}



@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private void userSignUp() {

    String temp = editTextstaff_id.getText().toString().trim();
    int staff_id = 0;
    if (!"".equals(temp)) {
        staff_id = Integer.parseInt(temp);
    } else {
        editTextstaff_id.setError("Staff ID Is Required");
        editTextstaff_id.requestFocus();
        return;
    }


    String email = editTextemail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextpassword.getText().toString().trim();
    String password2 = editTextpassword2.getText().toString().trim();


    if (email.isEmpty()) {
        editTextemail.setError("Email is required");
        editTextemail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        editTextemail.setError("Enter a valid email");
        editTextemail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (password.isEmpty()) {
        editTextpassword.setError("Password required");
        editTextpassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (password2.isEmpty()) {
        editTextpassword2.setError("Confirmation Password Required");
        editTextpassword2.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (!Objects.equals(password, password2)) {
        editTextpassword.setError("Passwords Do Not Match");
        editTextpassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    Call <ResponseBody> call =RetrofitClient
            .getInstance()
            .getApi()
            .signup(staff_id,email,password,password2);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            if (response.code() == 201){
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this,response.body().string(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (response.code() == 400){
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this,response.errorBody().string(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this,t.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

//

```
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonSignUp:
            userSignUp();
            break;
        case R.id.text_already_have_account:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
            break;

    }
}
```

}
`

I have tried the following;
1.  Annotated the Signup call with @Headers to specify Accept and Content-Type
2.  Modified my Django API code to include content type as well.
None of which have helped. I have also scoured through Stack Overflow to find a solution and everything I’ve tried still did not work.
I would appreciate any help to point me in the right direction. Is it my android code or do I have to modify the Django Rest API? The latter is unlikely given that I get the correct response on Postman.
Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: @Nikem Did you wait post body in your api, or form data?

Comment: Hi Rasul, Thank you for responding, I didnt quite get your question. Did you meanThe Postman API Image I Posted Up here ?

Comment: What is your `ResponseBody`?

Comment: {
    "error_message": "That email is already in use.",
    "response": "Error"
}

Comment: ResponseBody.java ?

Comment: <DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 transitional//EN>
<html>
<head>
<title>400</title>
<meta http-eqiv="Cache-Control"
content ="no-cache"/>
</head>
<body>
<p>
Bad Request 
</p>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! For anyone who is facing this, the problem is with the API itself. In my Django Rest API Serializer, I had some of my responses like:

```
 return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST) 
 return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

Now this was the issue for Retrofit cos it changes the response from a successful response **(code 200)** to an error response which in turn returns an error when attempting to view the **response.body()** in retrofit. The response is only available in **response.errorbody()** which returns some strange okhttp stuff that dosen’t help at all!!
Instead what I should have done in my API was:
First define an empty list:

```
context={}
```

Then add the error values with

```
context['status'] = 'Error'
        context['message'] = 'Invalid credentials'
        context['code']=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
        return Response(data=context)
```

This returns
[Postman Image Of Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vra1A.png)

Which is perfect and can be easily modelled into a Java Class or Pojo as you wish. As the API’s Actual response code is 200, the response.body() is available and won’t return an error.
That was the issue!